# Numbers to dates

Tags: vba, excel

I have a date in number form which looks like this: `20150529` is there a way to convert this into `29/05/2015` ?

I need to write a macro for this.

I have this code but it doesn't work:

```
Dim Current_Date As Date
Dim Date_String As String


Range("K2").Select
Date_String = Range("K2").Value
Current_Date = CDate(Date_String)
Range("Q2").Select
Range("Q2").Value = Current_Date
```

Comment: what did you try? What did not work ? SO is for programming questions, not to find free coders.

Comment: Dim Current_Date As Date
Dim Date_String As String


Range("K2").Select
Date_String = Range("K2").Value
Current_Date = CDate(Date_String)
Range("Q2").Select
Range("Q2").Value = Current_Date

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Range.TextToColumns method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193593.aspx) can make quick work of one or more cells in a selection or an entire column of 20150629 like dates.

```
sub YMD_2_Date
    with selection
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
                       FieldInfo:=Array(0, 5)
    end with
end sub
```

The [xlColumnDataType property](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193030.aspx) of **xlYMDFormat** (e.g. **5**) forces Excel to consider the number as *Year-Month-Day*.

This could be expanded from a selection (one or more cells in a single column) to multiple columns by cycling through them.

Comment: Splendid. Much more efficient than my answer in this case. Did not know this (I am too old :)

Comment: As a bonus this can also be done manually (1 column at a time). This is incredibly fast.

Answer (score 1):

You have to rearrange your string in American format first (mm/dd/yyyy).
Then you can use CDate().

```
r = Mid(Date_String , 5, 2) & "/" & Right(Date_String , 2) & "/" & Left(Date_String , 4)
current_date = CDate(r)
```

Answer (score 0):

This also works now

```
Range("K2", Range("K2").End(xlDown)).Select
                    For Each c In Selection.Cells
                        c.Value = DateSerial(Left(c.Value, 4), Mid(c.Value, 5, 2), Right(c.Value, 2))
                        'Following line added only to enforce the format.
                        c.NumberFormat = "mm/dd/yyyy"
                        Next
```